# Reading Nested XML and Loading to Redshift Efficiency

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I have this XML file residing in S3 that I would need to be able to load to respective tables in Redshift.

I would just like to check what is an efficient way to do such using Scala? I'm very new to this one and would like to seek some advice.

Do I create a single script that would chunk out required elements or would a separate script both reading from the same XML file for each table be more efficient? Or will AWS Glue be able to handle such nested XML formats?

**XML Data**

```
<Root>
<system>
    <head>
        <Store>123</Store>
        <storedate>2018-09-04</storedate>
    </head>
    <body>
        <SalesTxn>
            <Store>123</Store>
            <storedate>2018-09-04</storedate>               
            <txndetail>
                <sequence>1</sequence>                  
                <txngroup>
                    <Item>
                        <itemid>ABC</itemid>
                        <price>6.900000</price>
                        <quantity>1</quantity>

                    </Item>
                </txngroup>
            </txndetail>
            <txndetail>
                <sequence>2</sequence>      
                <txngroup>
                    <Item>
                        <itemid>DEF</itemid>
                        <price>6.890000</price>                         
                        <quantity>1</quantity>                          
                    </Item>
                </txngroup>
            </txndetail>                
            <total>
                <totalamount>13.79</totalamount>
            </total>
            <totalitems>
                <itemsnumber>2</itemsnumber>
            </totalitems>               
        </SalesTxn>
    </body>
</system>
```

**Desired Result**

Transaction Level

```
Store|StoreDate|ItemID|Price|Qty
123|2018-09-04|1|6.9|1
123|2018-09-04|2|6.89|1
```

Receipt Level

```
Store|StoreDate|TotalAmt|TotalQty
123|2018-09-04|13.79|2
```

Answer (score 0):

A Google search for Redshift+XML seems to indicate there is no native support (all the results are posts by various pipelining products - Alooma, Fivetran, etc - offering assistance with loading XML into Redshift). Indeed the **Redshift documentation indicates XML is unsupported** ...

both as a format:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html

and as a function:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html.

With this in mind, it'd be good to understand in more detail your choice of Redshift for this application. Alternatively, it might be useful to consider [Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/easily-load-xml-sql/) as one option which **does have native support for XML**.